# Help to translate sentence

Tags: translation

> 会社の同僚に彼女とのデートを目撃されてきまりが悪かった

I tried to translate this : i feel awkward because i was witnessed by my coworker friend dating her
に here means by?
Is this true?

Comment: `に here means by` -- What else do you think it is? Btw you're aware that the sentence is Indirect Passive/間接受け身 (eg 「私は彼に足を踏まれた。」「私は泥棒に財布を盗まれた。」)?

Comment: Ah yes!! Because of ~される at first i didnt know the meaning of きまりが悪かった, thats why it became hard to understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a passive sentence inside of an expression of the emotion felt by the speaker.

> 会社の同僚に彼女とのデートを目撃されてきまりが悪かった

So we've got  ... きまり悪かった as the main verb of the sentence and means "was embarrassed." The unspoken subject is the person making the sentence = "I"

> `I was embarrassed ...`

So now we can turn to the part inside:

> 会社の同僚に彼女とのデートを目撃されて

First let's think about that verb:

- 目撃する = to witness
- 目撃された = to be witnessed (to be seen)

Filled out:

```
XにAを目撃された
```

= Subject was seen by X doing A.

In this case X = 会社の同僚 (coworker)
A = 彼女とのデート (being on a date with my girlfriend).

> [I] was seen on a date with my girlfriend by my coworker.

Add back the main verb

> I was embarrassed when I was seen by a coworker while I was on a date with my girlfriend.

(I've picked "girlfriend" but it's also possible to just have "her" in this context).

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!!!! Was confused at first!! But now i understand thanks for divided it to part and explained very clearly!!